# FIGMA NOT ALLOWING TEXT RESIZING ONLY IN ONE DIRECTION

Tags: text, resize, figma

I want to resize a text in Figma but only horizontally not vertically (I don't want to alter the height), I can do it with images but somehow I cannot do it with texts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to stretch the font of text layer, as if you're resizing a vector image:**

1. Create a copy of the text layer you want to stretch.
2. Press `CTRL+E` to convert that text layer to vector format.
3. Resize the vector horizontally.

[image]

[image]

---

**If you want to scale-resize your text layers as if you are resizing image layers:**

For that, you need Figma's **Scale Tool**. Press `K` to activate this tool, then drag the corner of your text layer to scale-resize the text layer. *See screenshots below.*

Remember to re-activate the Move Tool afterwards, so that you won't accidentally scale-resize other layers. Press `V` to reactivate this tool.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The UI (or API) of Figma doesn't allow for independent axis scale transform, but the native Figma format does support it.

Using the clipboard and the [Stretch](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1288508418281450054/stretch) plugin, you can achieve it:

[image]